# Text-domain issue in WordPress Theme Development

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

We are developing the theme in WP but we are facing wired issue:

**Warning: More than one text-domain is being used in this theme. This means the theme will not be compatible with WordPress.org language packs.
The domains found are blog-theme, blog-theme**

How can we solve like this issue can anyone suggest me?

Comment: That means you are using multiple `text domain` in your theme. Read this https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/internationalization/#text-domain. Hope it helps.

Comment: this means we can add text domain by only one method i.e:  text-domain tag in style.css or load_child_theme_textdomain() function or As an argument in the localization functions. is this what you are trying to saying?Because we have only used theme-blog as a text domain and it's giving more than one text domain blog-theme,blog-theme since both are same how can it be more than one?

Comment: `text-domain` is not a method, it is used for translation/internationalization. It should be same through out the theme. If you are building any theme to submit at wordpress.org you have to follow this rule.

Comment: `esc_html_e('Hello', 'text-domain' );` you need to use in this way. and every function using text-domain will be same as mentioned in `style.css`

Comment: yes this has done but also it giving the warning with more than one text domain is used and it is saying blog-theme, blob-theme text domain

Comment: That means somewhere it still using any different `text-domain`. Search with the that text-domain within the theme files.

Comment: i have searched in theme folder and all over the theme folder there is blog-theme name only,all over the theme folder and when i searched with blog-theme inside the theme folder there is blog-theme but my question is since all over the theme folder we have placed blog-theme then how can it be more than one times?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206352/discussion-between-ajay-paudel-and-tristup).